# Reverse list Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

Given the following code:

```
import scala.util.Random

object Reverser {

  // Fails for big list
  def reverseList[A](list : List[A]) : List[A] = {
    list match {
      case Nil => list
      case (x :: xs) => reverseList(xs) ::: List(x)
    }
  }

  // Works
  def reverseList2[A](list : List[A]) : List[A] = {
    def rlRec[A](result : List[A], list : List[A]) : List[A] = {
      list match {
        case Nil => result
        case (x :: xs) => { rlRec(x :: result, xs) }
      }
    }
    rlRec(Nil, list)
  }

  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val random = new Random
    val testList = (for (_ <- 1 to 2000000) yield (random.nextInt)).toList
    // val testListRev = reverseList(testList) <--- Fails
    val testListRev = reverseList2(testList)
    println(testList.head)
    println(testListRev.last)
  }
}
```

Why the first version of the function fails (for big inputs), while the second variant works . I suspect it's something related to tail recursion, but I am not very sure . Can somebody please give me "for dummies" explanation ?

Comment: Why not use 'val testListRev = testList.reverse'?

Comment: This question was asked a long time ago, but here's the answer to your tail recursion question. Yes it is because of tail recursion optimization. In your first implementation, case (x :: xs) => reverseList(xs) ::: List(x), after calling reverseList recursively, the program has to add List(x) to it. This means that it can't be optimzed into a loop, in your second example: case (x :: xs) => { rlRec(x :: result, xs) } rlRec is the last call, nothing to do after it exits, and this is why it does not have to create a new Stack frame for it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok let me try tail recursion for dummies

If you follow what has to be done with reverseList, you will get

```
reverseList(List(1,2,3, 4))
reverseList(List(2,3,4):::List(1)
(reverseList(List(3,4):::List(2)):::List(1)   
((reverseList(List(4):::List(3)):::List(2)):::List(1)
Nil:::List(4):::List(3):::List(2):::List(1)
List(4,3,2,1)
```

With rlRec, you have

```
rlRec(List(1,2,3,4), Nil)
rlRec(List(2,3,4), List(1))
rlREc(List(3,4), List(2,1))
rlRec(List(4), List(3,2,1))
rlRec(Nil, List(4,3,2,1))
List(4,3,2,1)
```

The difference is that in first case, the rewriting keeps getting longer. You have to remember thing to do after the last recursive call to `reverseList` will have completed: elements to add to the result. The stack is used to remember that. When this goes too far, you get a stack overflow. On the opposite, with `rlRec`, the rewriting has the same size all along. When the last `rlRec` completes, the result is available. There is nothing else to do, nothing to remember, no need for the stack. The key  is that in `rlRec`, the recursive call is `return rlRec(something else)` while in `reverseList` it is `return f(reverseList(somethingElse))`, with `f` beging `_ ::: List(x)`. You need to remember you will have to call `f` (which implies remembering `x` too) ( return not needed in scala, just added for clarity. Also note that  `val a = recursiveCall(x); doSomethingElse()` is the same as `doSomethingElseWith(recursiveCall(x))`, so it is not a tail call)

When you have a recursive tail call

```
def f(x1,...., xn)
    ...
    return f(y1, ...yn)
    ...
```

there is actually no need to remember the context of the first `f` for when the second one will return. So it can be rewritten

```
def f(x1....xn)
start:
    ...
    x1 = y1, .... xn = yn
    goto start
    ...
```

That is what the compiler does, hence you avoid the stack overflow.

Of course, function `f` needs to have a return somewhere which is not a recursive call. That is where the loop created by `goto start` will exit, just as it is where the recursive calls series stops.

Answer (score 18):

Function is called `tail recursive` when it call itself as it's last action. You can check if the function is `tail recursive` by adding `@tailrec` annotation.

Answer (score 11):

You can make your tail-recursive version as simple as the non-tail-recursive version by using a **default argument** to give an initial value for the results:

```
def reverseList[A](list : List[A], result: List[A] = Nil) : List[A] = list match {
  case Nil => result
  case (x :: xs) => reverseList(xs, x :: result)
}
```

Although you can use this in the same way as the others, i.e. `reverseList(List(1,2,3,4))`, unfortunately you're exposing an implementation detail with the optional `result` parameter. Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to hide it. This may or may not worry you.

Comment: The Scala `List` class features a method called `reverse_:::` that does almost exactly this. The docs describe what it does like so: "Adds the elements of a given list in reverse order in front of this list". Suddenly, that "extra" argument is a feature! We can do `someList reverse_::: Nil` to reverse it, or `someList reverse_::: otherList` to reverse `someList` onto the front of `otherList`. It's often the case that with a little "rebranding", the extra argument you add to a function in order to support tail recursion (called an accumulator) actually generalises the purpose of your method.

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned, tail-call elimination avoids growing the stack when it is not needed. If you're curious about what the optimization does, you can run

```
scalac -Xprint:tailcalls MyFile.scala
```

...to show the compiler intermediate representation after the elimination phase. (Note that you can do this after any phase, and you can print the list of phases with scala -Xshow-phases.)

For instance, for your inner, tail-recursive function rlRec, it gives me:

```
def rlRec[A >: Nothing <: Any](result: List[A], list: List[A]): List[A] = {
  <synthetic> val _$this: $line2.$read.$iw.$iw.type = $iw.this;
  _rlRec(_$this,result,list){
    list match {
      case immutable.this.Nil => result
      case (hd: A, tl: List[A])collection.immutable.::[A]((x @ _), (xs @ _)) => _rlRec($iw.this, {
        <synthetic> val x$1: A = x;
        result.::[A](x$1)
      }, xs)
    }
  }
}
```

Nevermind there synthetic stuff, what matters is that _rlRec is a label (even though it looks like a function), and the "call" to _rlRec in the second branch of the pattern-matching is going to be compiled as a jump in bytecode.

Answer (score 6):

The first method is not tail recursive. See:

```
case (x :: xs) => reverseList(xs) ::: List(x)
```

The last operation invoked is `:::`, not the recursive call `reverseList`. The other one is tail recursive.

Answer (score 3):

```
def reverse(n: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  var a = n
  var b: List[Int] = List()
  while (a.length != 0) {
    b = a.head :: b
    a = a.tail
  }
  b
}
```

When you call the function call it like this,

```
reverse(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

then it will give answer like this,

```
res0: List[Int] = List(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```